# Python pandas pivot matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, pivot

I created the following python pandas pivot table.

```
df_pv = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Fiscal_Week"],columns=["Year"],values=["Category","Sales","Traffic"],
               aggfunc={"Category":len,"Sales":np.sum,"Traffic":np.sum},fill_value=0)

               Category             Sales                 Traffic       
Year    |2014 2015  2016 |  2014    2015    2016 |  2014    2015    2016
Fiscal_Week                                 
FW01      4    3    4       35678   654654  47547   567     231      765
FW02      2    6    7       6565    4686    34554   297     464      564
FW03      4    4    5       5867    56856   34346   287     45       324
FW04      2    5    3       8568    45745   3564    546     765      978
FW05      2    5    5       5685    3464    4754    325     235      654
FW06      4    3    2       56765   35663   3643    456     935      936
FW07      1    6    2       8686    2454    2463    324     728      598
FW08      6    2    3       34634   34543   4754    198     436      234
```

I would like to create the two following plots:

Scatterplot: Number of Campaigns by Sales and each year have it's own color.

[image]

The second graph should be Traffic by Fiscal Week.

[image]

I tried this unsucessfully

```
df_pv.plot(x="Fiscal_Week", y="Sales")

KeyError: 'Fiscal_Week'
```

Is there a better way - for example to not pivot, but within the graph specify the aggregations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the index as a normal column. That's not possible.

Ways to overcome this:

1. Reset the index `reset_index()`
2. Use the index explicitely `.plot(x=df_pv.index, y="Sales")`
3. Use the index implicitely `.plot(y="Sales", use_index=True)`